# Or(||) operation in `eval`

Tags: linux, unix

I found this `if` statement in `/etc/init/rc-initsys.conf`

```
# Check for default runlevel in /etc/inittab
    if [ -r /etc/inittab ]
    then
    eval "$(sed -nre 's/^[^#][^:]*:([0-6sS]):initdefault:.*/DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL="\1";/p' /etc/inittab || true)"
    fi
```

I don't understand the `or`(`||`) operation in the `eval` command.

Could you please give me some hint or reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first command fails, the second gets executed and will return a successful exit code. It ensures that the return value of the entire line (as e.g. in `$?`) is `true` (exit code `0`).

In general, subsequent commands, or, for actions at the end of a script, its caller, might check for the preceding action's return value to determine how to continue (i.e. error handling).

If you (as script author) don't want to report failure for a command, you can add `|| true` to it to always return a successful return code.
Depending on how the entire script is used, a single failing command outside of a condition could even abort execution.

Comment: And why this command needs to always return true ? Because the script starts with "set -e" which tell Bash to exit on any command returning false

Comment: That would be a reason – simple defensive programming @gre

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT That's what I meant in the last sentence. The command is allowed to fail without script abortion.

Comment: Thanks. But when will `sed` fail? In this case, if no `DEFAULTLEVEL` matched, it will simply exit will empty output. Will it fail in some circumstance?